# Understanding MVC design in iOS

Tags: ios, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

I'm trying to get my head around understanding MVC for iOS, and i'd like to make sure what i'm doing is appropriate.

Let's say i have a simple class which contains an NSMutableArray of NSString*

```
@interface SimpleClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *names;

@end
```

so this is my MODEL. Yes?

Let's say i wanted to write a method which sorted these names alphabetically. Should this method be a method in the model, or done separately in a data controller class? To me, it would make more sense to have this method in the model. So the model does the actual sorting, and the controller is the place where the sorting is initialised?

Does that sound right?

But, since sorting the data is something that is required by the view to display, is this really basic behaviour of the model?

Comment: view displays `sorted data`, the process of sorting is `controller`

Comment: Cool. Thanks. 

What about if we had a 3-D object, say a cube.

Then if we translated or rotated the cube by a certain amount - would we do this in the model, since the model data itself is changing?

Comment: Or do we manipulate the model in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to apply MVC in iOS we have 2 part specially model and viewContoller here view and controller is combine in iOS you may create separate  view and controller if you want.

now  in your question  you create one class with NSMutable array that would be you model class.

now you say that you want to sort your data than you can do this on viewContoller here in iOS 
view and controller are combine so you can do operation on data in controller part and display result on view.

but if you want to create separate  view for display operation you can crate UIView and add to view controller.

like if you create application that have deal with web service than you can do something like that

1. create model class like you done that set and get (property)data form server
2. crate DAO (Data access object) that manage all you web service call and fetch data from sever and set it in to model.
3. in viewController(UIview controller) operate on data and display in view
   or 3. crate spepate view for display data do all operation on model data in view controller and set model data to view and add this view to viewcontroller.

hope this is help you for more detail refer this links
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/ios-design-patterns-model-view-controller-part-3
This may help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify all your doubts one by one

**Question** : Let's say i have a simple class which contains an NSMutableArray of NSString*

so this is my MODEL. Yes?

**Answer** : Yes it is model class because it will be serving only a single purpose in the world that is "handling data"

**Question** : Let's say i wanted to write a method which sorted these names alphabetically. Should this method be a method in the model, or done separately in a data controller class? To me, it would make more sense to have this method in the model. So the model does the actual sorting, and the controller is the place where the sorting is initialised?

**Answer** : This method should be in view, because it is just sorting the data according to your needs, someday in future you might need this data sorted in some other way. Or you might need to develop this application for some other device also. and because of some other requirements you might need to sort it in some other way. If you will be doing this in model class or on controller class then you are restricting your code to be scalable therefore it should be in view class.

And controller will be implementing all the business logics.

I hope this helps